# system.web.routing on a web server not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I have read all these articles about how to make system.web.routing work but all these articles explains on localhost:port. I can get this working on the local machine, but as soon as I upload the site on the server, the Routing stops working no matter what I do.

First I was trying without any extension (.aspx) but after all efforts I gave up and added the extension, but still it does not work on the server.

Any help is appreciated.

sample:

### in `global.ascx`

```
Route test = new Route("home.aspx", new TestRoutingHandler());
Routes.Add(test);
```

### in Routing handler

```
public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    string virtualPath = string.Empty;
    Route route = (Route)requestContext.RouteData.Route;
    virtualPath = "~/Default.aspx";
    return (Page)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page));
}
```

### In web.config under httpModules

```
add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
```

This is so simple and works on a local machine, but not on the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the web server is configured to handle all requests with ASP.NET (also called a wildcard handler). If not, it will only serve requests through ASP.NET if the exact requested path corresponds to a physical file on disk and has the .aspx extension. Obviously the Routing concept completely fails the first condition and usually the second.

Phil Haack has a [great walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) on how to do this in **IIS 6**.

For **IIS 7**, you just need to have the [correct modules and handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx#id0070014) specified under system.webServer in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

For IIS7+ i found adding to the web.config's  section suddenly made everything work:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Confusing as in VS running on the Cassini web server, it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am struglling for this issue for hours.